# recording call stack in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to debug a really large c++/c program in Visual Studio. Changing value of one parameter changes the result dramatically. I want to record a call stacks for both runs and diff them.

Does anybody know how to dump a call stack to a file in VS without setting breakpoints and using Select ALL/Copy in the window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [codeproject example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx) which uses the [StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680650(VS.85).aspx) API.

Comment: I've found another solution for my problem. But this seams promising.

Comment: Care to tell what your solution is then? :)

I really hate searching for an issue, finding a guy asking the very same question and then replying his own question with stuff like "oh nevermind, I found a solution"...

Comment: @BogdanKanivets: Could you please share your solution?

Comment: I second that @Jan !

Comment: @BogdanKanivets: Could you please share your solution?

Comment: Fermat wrote once: I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`System.Diagnostics.StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) to get a string representation of the current call stack and write that to a file. For example:

```
private static writeStack(string file)
{
    StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(true); // the "true" param here allows you to get the file name, etc.
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < trace.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            StackFrame frame = trace.GetFrame(i);
            writer.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", frame.GetFileName(), frame.GetFileLineNumber(), frame.GetMethod());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you want to write the current stack, just call `writeStack(somePath)`.

Comment: Is this C / C++ or C#, and therefore inapplicable?

Comment: Whilst this is C# I was searching for C# so this answer is still very useful.